# knockout js syntax breaks in vs2015

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2015

Before I was use VS2013 for knockout development.

Currently, I Install VS2015 and some of knockout data binding break in vs2015.

e.g.

```
<select  data-bind="clientId,
                   options:clientList,
                   optionsValue:'Id',
                   value:ClientId,
                   optionsText: 'Name' ,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select Client' ">
</select>
```

When i press `Ctl + k + d` it change as following

```
<select  data-bind="clientId,
                   options clientList,
                   optionsValue:'Id',
                   value:ClientId,
                   optionsText  'Name' ,
                   optionsCaption 'Select Client' ">
</select>
```

it removes the `:` from code.

any answer?

Comment: Not sure if it's of any help, but I just tried to reproduce in _Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2_ and everything worked fine: `ctrl + k + d` didn't touch the formatting. Maybe it's a plugin?

Comment: Second previous comment. Try disabling all plugins to see if that helps.

Comment: you can test if you have both 2013 and 2015 write above code in vs2013 and than just open it in vs2015 and press `Ctl + k +d`

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in VS2015 4.6.00079 and cant replicate your error.
Check ur settings under Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> JavaScript -> formatting